# Exact Sequence with Ext Functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, derived-functors

We have exact sequence of groups $0\rightarrow A'\rightarrow A\rightarrow A''\rightarrow 0$ and an injective resolution of group $G$: 
$0\rightarrow G\rightarrow I^0\rightarrow I^1\rightarrow 0$.
 Since $I^*$ are injective we get
$$0\rightarrow Hom(A'',I)\rightarrow Hom(A,I)\rightarrow Hom(A',I)\rightarrow 0$$
and hence we have a short exact sequence of cochain complexes
$$0\rightarrow Hom(A'',I^*)\rightarrow Hom(A,I^*)\rightarrow Hom(A',I^*)\rightarrow 0.$$
Now I want to get (not very) long exact sequence in homology:
$$0\rightarrow Hom(A'',G)\rightarrow Hom(A,G)\rightarrow Hom(A',G)\rightarrow  Ext(A'',G)\rightarrow Ext(A,G)\rightarrow Ext(A',G)\rightarrow 0$$

When I draw a diagram, I think I found the way (a map) how elements from $Hom(A',G)$ go in $Ext(A'',G)$, but I don't know how to show that the exactness holds. Any idea?

I thaught that last two $Ext$'s will be easier, but I don't see now how to show the exatness too.

Comment: There is a typo in your exact sequence, there's no "$\to 0 \to$" in the middle.

Comment: What you are asking about is the following general result: a short exact sequence of complexes $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ induces a long exact sequence in cohomology $\cdots \to H^n (A) \to H^n (B) \to H^n (C) \to H^{n+1} (A)\to \cdots$. The morphisms $\delta^n\colon H^n (C) \to H^{n+1} (A)$ are constructed via the snake lemma.

Comment: I have finished this problem already. I read some about $Ext$ and $Tor$ functor and it is clear now. I know that a short exact sequence of (co-)chain complexes induces a long exact sequence in (co-)homology, but I didn't noticed that i my case $H^0(Hom(A^{\circ},I^*))=Hom(A^{\circ},G)$ and analogously the first group of cohomology is $Ext$ (and the sequence in cohomology is not very long, because the injective resolution if of length $2$).

Comment: I edited the sequence, thank you :)